# Android spinner is not left aligned when set to wrap_content

Tags: android, layout, operating-system, spinner, alignment

My spinner on 2.3:

[image]

and on 4.0:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.planets, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Please select a planet:"
    />

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And array resource,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets">
        <item>a</item>
        <item>aa</item>
        <item>aaa</item>
        <item>aaaa</item>
        <item>aaaaa</item>
        <item>aaaaaa</item>
        <item>aaaaaaa</item>
        <item>aaaaaaaa</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I realize that on 2.3, the spinner layout width will base on spinner item content, while as it fixes for widest content, and doesn't change for the others on 4.0. There is no problem if the spinner layout is set to fill_parent, but I need a wrap_content spinner...

Do you know how to make it consistent on both system? Since it looks ugly when the content lengths are very different.

Thank you.

Comment: @Agarwal layout file added :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using the layout weight set to spinner.
2. Another possiblity is setwidth of the spinner programitically say half of the device width or one third of device width.

Comment: You mean try to set layout width after item selected, I try with code below s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
     int arg2, long arg3) {
    String item = arg0.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int width = item.length() * 20 + 50;
    arg0.getLayoutParams().width = width;
    arg0.invalidate();
   }
  }); but get no luck, since the spinner is drawn already, the layout width just effects for the next selection.